# Use of Possesive Pronouns

Tags: meaning-in-context, apostrophe

Say, I want to tell my readers to come visit the U.S. and enjoy American lifestyle (such as eating American hamburgers, watching football games, playing Beerpong, etc). Then which of the followings will be the best expression? (if I can't paraphrase it)

- Enjoy American's daily life.
- Enjoy American daily life.  (indefinite article?)
- Enjoy Americans' daily life.

[as a foreigner] enjoy (an /the /[blank]) (American's daily life/ American daily life/ Americans' daily life)

This is so subtle and seems like there is no meaningful difference in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Enjoy American's daily life.

This means *enjoy the daily life of an American individual*. I would add an indefinite article her: *Enjoy an American's daily life.*

> Enjoy American daily life.

Here, *American* simply modifies daily life: *enjoy daily life that is American*. No article needed, but you could add a *definite* article.

> Enjoy Americans' daily life.

This means *enjoy the daily life of American people*. The indefinite plural article is already there (null-article).

Which one is correct depends on the what you want to convey. Are you offering a "step in the shoes of a typical American"-style experience? Then the first option would certainly fit best.

Do you want to emphasise the lifestyle being *American*, or do you want to emphasise that it's about the *people*? Then chose your second or third option respectively.

Comment: That's for ell though.

Comment: The indefinite missing article (They had Ø1 chicken for tea) is the zero article, according to Master and others. The missing definite article (He was crowned Ø2 King) is the null article.